# Enterprise Support for Juju

Tags: juju, support

From whatever I have read and come to know about Juju, it is still a very much open source project. Does it also have an enterprise version/support subscription? More akin to Chef hosted services and puppet enterprise(enterprise grade versions and support for open source tools).

Would using Ubuntu Openstack with Juju help support for Juju at any level from Ubuntu Advantage/Cannonical?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can purchase cloud support plans from Canonical which include support for Juju itself as well as select charms.  Inquire here:

http://www.ubuntu.com/management/contact-us